# Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function on ajax call in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

i have a fullcalendar working on my app and i added the following method to filter results by user:

```
function filter_by_provider(selected_provider) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' );
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', function(start, end, callback) {
                $.getJSON(source, function(data){
                    var eventsToShow = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        if(data[i].provider == selected_provider || selected_provider == ""){
                            eventsToShow.push(data[i]);
                        };
                    };
                    callback(eventsToShow); //here's the Error
                });
            });
};
```

The thing is callback doesnt seem to be working and i keep getting this Error on that line:

```
Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function
```

Could it be that jquery is not properly installed? Am i missing something?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output if you `console.log(callback)`?

Comment: Hi @ptd. It's false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
```

It's in [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/):

> timezone is a string/boolean describing the calendar's current
>   timezone. It is the exact value of the timezone option.

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of callback object, its looks like your callback = true or false